# EF executestorequery throwing exception about - Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '30267-366492' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to execute a sql query using EF executestorequery.

The repository method that executes the query is as follows. It takes a list of Tuples (studentid, sectionid) and constructs a string of studentid-sectionid values which is the input parameter to the query.

```
public static List<EF.TraditionalGradingEntity> GetTraditionalGrading(List<Tuple<int, int>> studentSectionIds)
{
    List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
    foreach (Tuple<int, int> studentSectionId in studentSectionIds)
    {
        tempList.Add(studentSectionId.Item1.ToString() + "-" + studentSectionId.Item2.ToString());
    }
    string stuSecIds = string.Join(",", tempList.ToArray());
    string strTdlGradingQuery = string.Format(
        @"
        select 
            tbgTraj.studentPersonID,
            tbgTraj.sectionID,
            tbgTraj.studentPersonID_SectionID,
            tbgTraj.score,
            tbgTraj.sel,
            tbgTraj.growth,
            tbgTraj.warning,
            tbgTraj.taskID,
            tbgTraj.gradingTask,
            tbgTraj.taskScore,
            tbgScore.groupName,
            tbgScore.activityName,
            tbgScore.score activityScore
        from
            [shs].[DataCollector_TBG_Grade_Trajectory] tbgTraj
            inner join [shs].[DataCollector_TBG_Scores] tbgScore 
                on tbgTraj.taskID = tbgScore.taskID 
                and tbgTraj.studentPersonID = tbgScore.studentPersonID 
                and tbgTraj.sectionID = tbgScore.sectionID
        where
            tbgTraj.studentPersonID_SectionID in ({0})
        ", stuSecIds);

    using (EF.AESDBContext aesDBContext = new EF.AESDBContext())
    {
        return aesDBContext.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<EF.TraditionalGradingEntity>(strTdlGradingQuery, "TraditionalGradings", MergeOption.OverwriteChanges, null).ToList();
    }
}
```

My entity definition is as follows

```
public class TraditionalGradingEntity
{
    public int StudentPersonId { get; set; }
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public string StudentPersonID_SectionID { get; set; }
    public string Score { get; set; }
    public string Sel { get; set; }
    public string Growth { get; set; }
    public string Warning { get; set; }
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string GradingTask { get; set; }
    public string TaskScore { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public string ActivityName { get; set; }
    public string ActivityScore { get; set; }
}
```

Now, irrespective of the input parameter value, the execution always fails with the following exception:

```
System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232004
  Message=An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead()
       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at D125Portal.DA.EbrRepository.GetTraditionalGrading(List`1 studentSectionIds) in C:\Users\rgopinathan\Source\Workspaces\Workspace_D125New\EBRLevel\D125Portal\D125Portal.DataAccess\EbrRepository.cs:line 218
       at D125Portal.BL.EBR.ReportS.Init() in C:\Users\rgopinathan\Source\Workspaces\Workspace_D125New\EBRLevel\D125Portal\D125Portal.BL\EBR\ReportS.cs:line 73
       at D125Portal.BL.EBR.ReportManager.GetReport(ReportRequestS req) in C:\Users\rgopinathan\Source\Workspaces\Workspace_D125New\EBRLevel\D125Portal\D125Portal.BL\EBR\Report.cs:line 79
       at D125Portal.WWW.Areas.EBR.Coordinator.GetStudentReport(List`1 students) in C:\Users\rgopinathan\Source\Workspaces\Workspace_D125New\EBRLevel\D125Portal\D125Portal\Areas\EBR\Coordinator.cs:line 106
       at D125Portal.WWW.Areas.EBR.Controllers.EBRHomeController.Report() in C:\Users\rgopinathan\Source\Workspaces\Workspace_D125New\EBRLevel\D125Portal\D125Portal\Areas\EBR\Controllers\EBRHomeController.cs:line 164
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
  InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
       HResult=-2146232060
       Message=Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '30267-366492' to data type int.
       Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
       ErrorCode=-2146232060
       Class=16
       LineNumber=2
       Number=245
       Procedure=""
       Server=ovdcovyjrr.database.windows.net
       State=1
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
            at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead()
       InnerException:
```

Note: The value '30267-366492' in the exception message is always the same irrespective of the input parameter value and the output data (even when the output doesn't contain this value). I am able to run the query separately successfully but not through the program. Any insight or help is much appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to put single quotes around the values you join together and format into your query.

Comment: Yes, thanks. That helped. Because the exception was showing a particular value ('30267-366492'), I was so distracted as to from where it picked it and and also was repeatedly checking only the entity class mapping to make sure the data types were correctly assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tempList.Add(studentSectionId.Item1.ToString() + "-" + studentSectionId.Item2.ToString())
...
string stuSecIds = string.Join(",", tempList.ToArray());
```

Here you are presumably concatenating integers in a way that would resemble something like: `0-3, 1-4, 2-5`. So on the whole your where clause is: `where tbgTraj.studentPersonID_SectionID in (-3, -3, -3)`. Note these are `integers`since the `-` is interpreted as a subtraction. In your `tbgTraj.studentPersonID_SectionID` you've got the value `'30267-366492'`, which won't convert to an `int`. SQL server tries to implicitly convert it to an `int`, since in a comparison `string = int`, `int` takes precedence ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms190309.aspx)).

So your solution would be to use quotes around your id's:

```
"'" + studentSectionId.Item1.ToString() + "-" + + studentSectionId.Item2.ToString() "'" ...
```

Also, beware of [bobby tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296201(v=sql.105).aspx). You should parametrize your queries to avoid sql injection!

Comment: Thank you. Though the subtraction was not happening (as I had the ToString()), adding the single quotes around the id pairs helped overcome the exception.

Comment: The subtraction occurred in the sql interpretation. Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put single quotes around your list of id pairs so that you compare `studentPersonID_SectionID` to a set of strings instead of a set of integers (the numbers will end up subtracting in the SQL).

```
tempList.Add(string.Format(
    "'{0}-{1}'", 
    studentSectionId.Item1,
    studentSectionId.Item2));
```

Comment: Thank you. Though the subtraction was not happening (as I had the ToString()), adding the single quotes around the id pairs helped overcome the exception.

Comment: What I meant by subtraction is that you have something like `In (30267-366492)` in the SQL query and it would result in something like `In (-336225)` because the SQL server would treat `30267-366492` as a subtraction.

Comment: Ah, ok. Got you. Thank you for the responses, appreciate your help.